# What's the bigger number?

Tags: java

I want write a programme with Eclipse of Java such that the calculator reads a integer $k$ and then  it reads $k$ integers establishing the bigger between $k$ integers.
My attempt:

```
public class biggerKintegers {

static Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main (String[] args){

int num= input.nextInt();

for(int k=0; k<num; k++){

int p= input.nextInt();
```

How can I continue?

Comment: Is there more to your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Simply store and update the current max value:

```
int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int k=0; k<num; k++) {
    int p = input.nextInt();
    currentMax = Math.max(p, currentMax);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, you should compare the entered value to a maximum, and update the maximum if the entered value is greater.